# The type is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly

Tags: c#, ssis, assemblies

I've been at this for a while, unable to figure out what the cause is.

`Error  1   The type 'Google.Apis.Requests.IErrorResponseHandler' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'Google.Apis, Version=1.2.4737.25313, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'.

    Error   2   The type 'Google.Apis.Authentication.IAuthenticator' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'Google.Apis, Version=1.2.4737.25313, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'.

    Error   3   The type 'Google.Apis.Discovery.IRequestProvider' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'Google.Apis, Version=1.2.4737.25316, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'.`

Comment: Have you tried to add the Google.Apis library through NuGet ?

Comment: @Ronnix I haven't tried this. But doesn't NuGet supports 2010/2012? Im using 2008.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the reference to your project:

Go to `Solution Explorer` window, expand the node of your project (if not already expanded), right click on `References`, browse where is located the assembly (if is already in GAC select it from Framework listing), add the reference.

Comment: Forgot to add it to my list but I already did this step. Edited my post.

Answer (score 0):

For SSIS to find the DLL, it will need to be **both** in the GAC **and** somewhere in the path that SSIS uses to find components. The .NET Framework folder **for the specific version of the framework** is a good place to put it; that would be `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727` for the .NET Framework 2.0 (which is what SSIS 2005 and 2008R2 uses) or `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319` for the .NET Framework 4.0 (which I believe is the one SSIS 2012 uses).

Comment: This is one of the steps I've tried. I tried all the folders actually starting with v2.0.50727 but no luck. I'm using framework 3.5.

Comment: Assuming this is being used by a script component or script task, what .NET Framework version is the specific script using?

Comment: The script component is using framework 3.5.